# avrdude.conf: programmer type must be written as "id_type"?

Tags: avrdude, ino

I'm trying to compile & run using ino.

At the `ino upload` step I get the following error:

`avrdude: error at /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf:332: programmer type must be written as "id_type"`

Relevant section of `avrdude.conf`:

`programmer
  id    = "wiring";
  desc  = "Wiring";
  type  = wiring;   # line 332
;`

I've seen various posts around the internet that suggest I just delete the config & refresh it, but I'd like to find the correct syntax and actually understand & fix the issue.

Comment: Which version of the IDE are you using? Did you download it from the Arduino site, or install using apt-get?

Comment: I'm not using an IDE, just ino: http://inotool.org/

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the [source repo](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/avrdude/avrdude.conf.in?root=avrdude&view=markup) it looks like quotes are now required:

`type  = "wiring";`